# Object is not JSON-Valid: Database Error

Tags: ethminer

Having a difficult time with mininig for Eth. GPU does not have enough RAM, so that's out of the picture, but it's fine. I do this for fun and learning...

When I mine with CPU, it does a few hashes, and then errors galore:

```
miner  11:38:14.090|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #e6d67189… : 224672 H/s = 188500 hashes / 0.839 s
  ✘  11:38:14.261|ethminer  Failed to submit hashrate.
  ✘  11:38:14.261|ethminer  Dynamic exception type: jsonrpc::JsonRpcException
std::exception::what: Exception -32700 : JSON_PARSE_ERROR: The JSON-Object is not JSON-Valid:  Database Error
```

In the background, I have geth --rpc running to have it catch up to the Blockchain. Not sure if anything got corrupted? Is that what those errors are? This is running on a Ubuntu 16.04 VM with 8GB RAM

```
# ethminer --version
ethminer version 1.2.9
Build: Linux/g++/Interpreter/RelWithDebInfo
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. If this happens to you, you may have a corrupt hashes in your ~/.ethash folder. Simply remove the files and restart your miner and/or geth --rpc invocation.